# How to send JSON data to CGI Perl Script in AngularJS and read back in Perl

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, perl

I am using the following code for sending JSON Data to perl script.

```
ProductService.AddNewProduct = function(NewProduct)  {

    var ProductData = {};
    ProductData = NewProduct;
    ProductData = JSON.stringify(ProductData);
    alert (ProductData);

    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: "cgi-bin/AddNewProduct2.pl",
        params: { NewProduct: ProductData }
    };

    $http(req).success(function()
    {
        alert ('New Product Added!');
    })
    .error(function()
    {
        alert ('New Product Add Error!');
    });

}
```

The alert is alerting this data.

```
{"ProductID":873,"ProductName":"sds","ProductImagePath":"/images/adidas/873.png","SubCategoryID":"153","SubCategoryName":"Cream Biscuits","BrandID":"162","BrandName":"Adidas","Variants":[]}
```

In perl script trying to get this data as follow:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $DecodedData = decode_json($cgi->param("NewProduct"));

my $product_id = $DecodedData->{'ProductID'};
my $product_name = $DecodedData->{'ProductName'};
my $product_description = 'Desc';
my $image_path = $DecodedData->{'ProductImagePath'};
my $brand_id = $DecodedData->{'BrandID'};
my $subcatty_id = $DecodedData->{'SubCategoryID'};
```

But none of the Perl variables are getting filled with data.

What is the issue? Can please someone help me.

Comment: Where's your error checking? See: http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-4.21/lib/CGI.pod#Retrieving_cgi_errors And who still uses CGI?

Comment: @NeilHWatson what is the alternative of CGI.

Comment: Frameworks are the expected web tools. Mojolicious (my favourite), Dancer, and Catalyst are the big Perl ones.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal See [`CGI::Alternatives`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives)